# How to pixelate/blur an image using ImageMagick?

Tags: imagemagick

I want to pixelate and/or blur an image.
I've found the command for the blurring:

```
$convert image.jpg -blur 18,5 newimage.jpg
```

to work but I cannot blur the image any more. 
And how do I pixelate the image? I couldn't find a sound example around the net.

Thx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This worked nicely for me, gives a sort of cross between pixelating and blurring:

```
convert -resize 10% image.jpg newimage.jpg
convert -resize 1000% newimage.jpg newimage.jpg
```

You can be sure that the data cannot be retrieved, should that be important to you.

Changing the %ages will change the amount of pixelation/blur

Comment: `-filter Point` gives strict pixelization

Answer (score 54):

To get a proper square pixellation, try:

```
convert -scale 10% -scale 1000% original.jpg pixelated.jpg
```

Answer (score -6):

I don't know anything about ImageMagick, but you can try resizing the image using bicubic to a much smaller dimension, then resizing the image back to a bigger one.

The trick works using .net's System.Drawing object.

Comment: Actually, the validity of the question is still intact, so it doesn't matter. Anyways, I just saw the year dude, my bad..sorry!