# How to pixelate image in moviepy?

Tags: moviepy

I want to make a pixelate image in moviepy, I have reference the following Doc:

- Moviepy: https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/ref/videofx/moviepy.video.fx.all.resize.html

And tried the following:

```
clip = ImageClip("source.jpg").resize(0.01).resize(100)
```

While it does make the video blur, it does not produce a pixelated image.

What I want to do is something like the below:

- Imagemagick: [How to pixelate/blur an image using ImageMagick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/331254/how-to-pixelate-blur-an-image-using-imagemagick)

However, I want to prevent using imagemagick natively if possible. Would like to know if it is possible, thanks.

Comment: Have a look at the source file (https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/blob/master/moviepy/video/fx/resize.py) and see whether a different resizing method (interpolation etc) might help?

Comment: Thanks, big help pointing me to the code! Though at first glance I don't find any ways to make it work like i intended, let me continue research on the code, thanks!